# Получить номер ряда из общей выборки mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть общий запрос вида:

```
SELECT id FROM test BY time DESC
```

Выдаются результаты вида:

```
order - id  
  1   - 2 
  2   - 69
  3   - 111
```

Как максимально просто зная `id` понять, какой у него будет порядковый номер(`order`) в таком запросе?

P.S. если изложил неясно - напишите в комменты. Попробую еще раз

Comment: Нужно получить порядковый номер именно. Вы это, так понимаю, назвали "пронумеровать"

Comment: @Mike, я не знаю что mysql делает с записями с одинаковым временем при сортировке по времени. Это вы не по адресу вопрос задали. Если я делаю запрос по всем рядам, и руками их перебираю, то запись с id Y занимает в пятое место. (Перед ней ещё четыре ряда). Как мне узнать это не делая запрос по всем рядам и не перебирая их потом руками в коде?

Comment: Ну по умолчанию SQL (любой) возвращает записи как ему вздумается. так что сегодня с датой равной X у вас будут идти id 3 8 45, а завтра sql имеет полное право выдать их вам в порядке  45 3 8. так что надо просто определится, в каком порядке хотите видеть. например определяемся, что внутри даты сортируем по id. сейчас тогда сделаю итоговую версию исходя из этого предположения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Номер записи в указанной вами выборке для ID=XX можно получить так:

```
select count(1)
  from test A,
       (select time, id from test where id=XX) B
 where A.time > B.time
    or (A.time=B.time and A.id<=B.id)
```

Наличие индекса по полю time очень приветствуется. Может потребоваться несколько усложнить условие для более оптимальному проходу по индексу. Но сделать это можно только по планам выполнения на реальной таблице с данными.